# Oracle ADF: af:selectOneChoice Hierarchy changes

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application using Oracle ADF. In that I have a page like as follows

[image]

In the above image I have two select lists. First one is country and second one is state. Actually my requirement is when the user select any value from country list I have to add all appropriate states to the states list programatically.

Suppose user has selected India then I need all states in India that are Ap, Ka, Mh, Tn like that.

I have tried this [This Post](http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/08/programmatically-populate-values-in.html). But it is fixed and I need to add values dynamically.

Please help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TThe way I would approach this is though programatic View Objects. ADF is build to work best with ADF BC

More exactly: I would create a simple VO based on SQL statement:

```
select '' as Country, '' as State from dual
```

For Country attribute, you need to create a programatic view object : CountryLOV. Same thing for State attribute - StateLOV.

This is not a simple task, but you can find quite a few examples around:

http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/detail-view-object-instance.html

http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/adf-bc-programmatically-populated-vo.html

http://www.jobinesh.com/2011/06/building-programmatically-managed.html

Comment: Hello marcus. I have gone through the above links. Thanks for your time. Actually I can hard code first list values. On change of this list value I need to set the values for second list in a managed bean. Can you suggest me any simpler way for this.??

Comment: I've looked at the blog post you tried first, can't you just refactor getCustomList() method to pick up the current Country value, then build your State list based on that value? You might need to set Country's autosubmit to true and expose Country's bindings on the backing bean.